# Using asyncio extension with SQLite backend broken by version upgrade

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, aiosqlite

An upgrade from SQLAlchemy version `1.4.0b2` to `1.4.0b3` results in the following error when attempting to connect to a SQLite engine, using the asyncio extension.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
>>> engine = create_async_engine('sqlite:///database.db', echo=True, future=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<...>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py", line 41, in create_async_engine
    return AsyncEngine(sync_engine)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py", line 531, in __init__
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: The asyncio extension requires an async driver to be used. The loaded 'pysqlite' is not async.
```

Is this due to an incompatibility between the SQLite driver and the asyncio extension? However if this was the case, why does it work on version `1.4.0b2`?

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
>>> engine = create_async_engine('sqlite:///database.db', echo=True, future=True)
>>> engine
<sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.engine.AsyncEngine object at 0x7f9530101180>
```

Also note that using the `asyncpg` driver for postgres works (url beginning `postgresql+asyncpg://`). All tests were performed using python version `3.9.2`.

I understand that the asyncio extension [should be regarded as 'alpha level'](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html), and therefore subject to change, but I would like to know whether this is a bug, or a problem specific to SQLite.

Comment: Is pysqlite asyncio-compatible? As you're using a beta release of SQLAlchemy it's quite possible that `create_async_engine` got better at detecting drivers that aren't.

Comment: This is not a bug but [by design](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5920). The b1 version didn’t check if the dbapi supports async calls!

Comment: Do we have any async sqlite driver ? (I found aiosqlite) And how to use it with sqlalchemy then?

Answer (score 14):

`aiosqlite` [is supported](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#aiosqlite), but you need to specify the driver in the connection string. Otherwise it will use `sqlite3` (i.e. `pysqlite`) by default.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
engine = create_async_engine('sqlite+aiosqlite:///database.db')
```